# JavaScript link data in object to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrayobject

I have a JavaScript exercise where I'm trying to have a table with data appear once a particular link is clicked. It's actually a 3 part exercise. 2 parts are complete. Only part I can't do is the table part. It's a drop down select menu where user choose a category. Once category is selected business from that category appear. Each business is a li tag and anchor link. Once the business link is clicked on it's suppose to jump down to the page and display a table with info on that particular business. Displaying the table with the data is my issue. Can someone help me while not changing the code I already have.

```js
var businessListings = {
    hair: {
      "Tina's Hair Salon": {
        Address: "1520 Lakeview Drive Chester, Pa 19013",
        PhoneNumber: "610-872-1109",
        Website: "www.tinahair.com",
        Specialty: "All hair types"
      }, // line ends Tina Hair Salon info
      "Dollhouse Hair Studio": {
        Address: "485 4th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
        PhoneNumber: "484-419-8595",
        Website: "www.dhhairstudio.com",
        Specialty: "Braiding, All hair types"
      } // line ends dollhouse info
    }, // line ends hair category
    healBeauty: {
      Myra 's Make-Up Kit": {
      Address: "4260 Jeffrey Lane Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-848-2014",
      Website: "www.mymakeupkit.com",
      Specialty: "Make all skin tones, ages, events"
    }, // line ends Myra's makeup info
    "Purity Spa": {
      Address: "213 W. 24th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-608-4752",
      Website: "www.purityspa.com",
      Specialty: "Universal"
    } // line ends Purity spa info
  }, // line ends healBeauty category
  food: {
    "Larry's Pies": {
      Address: "250 3rd Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-724-2008",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Pies, Desserts"
    }, // line ends Larry's Pies info
    "C-Pride Super Market": {
      Address: "3018 W. 7th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-803-2020",
      Website: "www.cpridemarket.com",
      Specialty: "All Foods, Groceries"
    } // line ends C-Pride Market info
  }, // line ends food category
  travel: {
    "G&W Travel Agency": {
      Address: "200 Avenue of States Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-203-8587",
      Website: "www.gandwtravel.com",
      Specialty: "Traveling, All Occasions"
    }, // line ends G&W Travel info
    "Grant Travel Agency": {
      Address: "1834 Edward Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-515-7062",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Traveling, All Occasions"
    } // line ends Grant Travel info
  }, // line ends travel category
  fitness: {
    "Elijah's Supreme Gym": {
      Address: "420 Tilghman Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-898-5040",
      Website: "www.esupremegym.com",
      Specialty: "Fitness, All Body Types"
    }, // line ends Elijah's Gym info
    "Fitness Girl Gym": {
      Address: "2790 E. 15th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-762-8240",
      Website: "www.esupremegym.com",
      Specialty: "Fitness, All Body Types"
    } // line ends Fitness Gym info
  },
  retCloth: {
    "Enid and 4 Girls Boutique": {
      Address: "2200 Edgmont Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-203-8570",
      Website: "www.enidand4girls.com",
      Specialty: "Clothing, Accessories"
    }, // line ends Enid and 4 Girls info
    "Fatima & Iman's Closet": {
      Address: "824 Parker Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-800-1937",
      Website: "www.fatimaandiman.com",
      Specialty: "Clothing, Accessories"
    } // line ends Enid and 4 Girls info
  }, // line ends retCloth info
  auto: {
    "Arthur's": {
      Address: "1019 Edgmont Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-626-1149",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "All Vehicle Issues"
    }, // line ends Arthur's info
    "Johnson and Son Mechanics": {
      Address: "517 Pennell Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-504-8127",
      Website: "www.johnsonandsons.com",
      Specialty: "Auto Body Work"
    } // line ends Johnson and Sons info
  }, // line ends auto info
  homeDec: {
    "Charisma Home Decor": {
      Address: "7790 Melrose Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-203-9045",
      Website: "www.charismahomedecor.com",
      Specialty: "Handcrafted Home Decor, Elegant Home Decor, All Styles"
    }, // line ends Charisma Home Decor info
    "Lily's Home Decor": {
      Address: "1402 Ward Road Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-761-2990",
      Website: "www.lilydesign.com",
      Specialty: "All Styles"
    } // line ends Lily Home Decor info
  }, // line ends homeDec info
  photo: {
    "Marple Photography": {
      Address: "618 Taylor Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-499-8615",
      Website: "www.marplephotography.com",
      Specialty: "All Styles, Occasions"
    }, // line ends Marple Photography info
    "Kyle's Photography": {
      Address: "216 W. 9th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-223-7831",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Professional Shoots, All Styles, Occasions"
    } // line ends Kyle's Photography info
  }, // line ends photo info
  musEnt: {
    "Mark's Studios": {
      Address: "2407 Linden Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-808-4256",
      Website: "www.markstudios.com",
      Specialty: "R&B, Hip Hop"
    }, // line ends Mark's Studios info
    "CC Moore Recording Studio": {
      Address: "1420 Melrose Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-615-2009",
      Website: "www.ccmoorestudio.com",
      Specialty: "All Genres"
    } // line ends CC Moore Recording info
  }, // line ends musEnt category paint: {
  "Ulysses's Paint": {
    Address: "2201 Edgmont Avenue Chester Pa 19013",
    PhoneNumber: "267-298-0845",
    Website: "www.ulyssespaint.com",
    Specialty: "Mixing Paint, Selling All Paint Types"
  }, // line ends Ulysses's Paint info
  "Dock Paint Supplies": {
    Address: "1007 W. 7th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
    PhoneNumber: "484-318-5190",
    Website: "N/A",
    Specialty: "All Paint Type Supplies"
  } // line ends Mark's Studios info
}, // line ends paint category info
}; // line ends "multi-dimensional" array object

var businessListNames = [];
var selectedCategory;
var textNameOfBusinessSelected;
var nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory;

function businessListingResults(databaseList) {
  // function is for when a category is selected
  selectedCategory = $("#select-business-listing option:selected").val();
  textNameOfBusinessSelected = $("#select-business-listing 
      option: selected ").text();
      nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory = databaseList[selectedCategory];
      for (findBusinessUnderCategory in nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory) {
        businessListNames.push(findBusinessUnderCategory);
        console.log(findBusinessUnderCategory);
      } // line ends for in loop
      console.log("ice cream"); $("#listingResults").html("Business Listings Under Category <strong>" +
        textNameOfBusinessSelected + "</strong> are: <br/><br/><ul 
        id = 'listOfBusinesses' > < li > < a href = 'javascript-exercise-16.html#bottomOfPage'
        onclick = 'clickListingLink()' > " + businessListNames.join(" < br / > < a href = 'javascript-exercise-16.html#bottomOfPage'
        onclick = 'clickListingLink()' >
        <
        li > ") + " < /li></ul > ");
      } // line closes function

      function clickListingLink() {
        // function is for when a link is clicked after list of businesses appear
        $('#listOfBusinesses').on('click', 'li', function() {
          clickListingLink();
          console.log('you clicked me');
          seeListingInfoTable();
          $("hr").show();
        });
      }

      function seeListingInfoTable(titleOfBusinessSelected, businessLinkSelected) {
        // function is for table that shows info of specific link clicked 
        console.log("apple");
        var tbl = "";
        tbl += '<table class="table table-hover">';
        tbl += '</table>';
        tbl += '<tbody>';
        tbl += '<caption class="listingTitle">' + titleOfBusinessSelected +
          '</caption>';
        tbl += '<tr>';
        tbl += '<th>Address</th>';
        tbl += '<th>Phone Number</th>';
        tbl += '<th>Website</th>';
        tbl += '<th>Specialty</th>';
        tbl += '</tr>';
        tbl += '<tr>';
        tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
          businessLinkSelected["Address"] + '</div></td>';
        tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
          businessLinkSelected["Phone Number"] + '</div></td>';
        tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
          businessLinkSelected["Website"] + '</div></td>';
        tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' +
          businessLinkSelected["Specialty"] + '</div></td>';
        tbl += '</tr>';
        tbl += '</tbody>';
        tbl += '</table>';
        $(document).find("#infoTable").html(tbl);
      } // line ends seeListingInfoTable function
```

```html
<h4 class="title">Select a Category from the drop down menu to check your local businesses</h4>
<br/>
<select id="select-business-listing" name="submitted[select_your_program]" class="select-a-business">
  <option value="" selected="selected">- Select a business category -</option>
  <option value="hair">Hair</option>
  <option value="healBeauty">Health and Beauty</option>
  <option value="food">Food</option>
  <option value="travel">Travel</option>
  <option value="fitness">Fitness</option>
  <option value="retCloth">Retail and Clothing</option>
  <option value="auto">Automotive</option>
  <option value="homeDec">Home Decor</option>
  <option value="photo">Photography</option>
  <option value="musEnt">Music and Entertainment</option>
  <option value="paint">Paint</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button class="listingsBtn" onclick="businessListingResults(businessListings)">Search Listings</button>
</div>
<p id="listingResults"></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<hr/>
<br/>
<div id="bottomOfPage">
  <div id="infoTable">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please put your code into an CSS/HTML/JS code block... or on a website like https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal**, complete, verifiable and well-formatted example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). This block of code is difficult to read and understand. -> [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: It's not minimal, but I at least moved the code into a snippet for them and hit tidy so it's a bit more manageable.

Comment: Ok my apologies about the formatting. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @Elias Here's my fiddle link > https://jsfiddle.net/Angel91/pe8vuq2f/

Comment: gonna look at it when I'm at home

Answer (score 0):

So, Hello :D "hopefully" the last time (in this post ;) ).

I have rewritten your code, now, it's not **your** code anymore but I think you should read 2 - 3 times through it and learn the bits from it you didn't know yet :). (it's a bit more structured).

Have a great day, Elias :)

```js
// Define Database
var businessListings = {
  hair: {
    "Tina's Hair Salon": {
      Address: "1520 Lakeview Drive Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-872-1109",
      Website: "www.tinahair.com",
      Specialty: "All hair types"
    },
    "Dollhouse Hair Studio": {
      Address: "485 4th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-419-8595",
      Website: "www.dhhairstudio.com",
      Specialty: "Braiding, All hair types"
    }
  },
  healBeauty: {
    "Myra 's Make-Up Kit": {
      Address: "4260 Jeffrey Lane Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-848-2014",
      Website: "www.mymakeupkit.com",
      Specialty: "Make all skin tones, ages, events"
    },
    "Purity Spa": {
      Address: "213 W. 24th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-608-4752",
      Website: "www.purityspa.com",
      Specialty: "Universal"
    }
  },
  food: {
    "Larry's Pies": {
      Address: "250 3rd Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-724-2008",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Pies, Desserts"
    },
    "C-Pride Super Market": {
      Address: "3018 W. 7th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-803-2020",
      Website: "www.cpridemarket.com",
      Specialty: "All Foods, Groceries"
    }
  },
  travel: {
    "G&W Travel Agency": {
      Address: "200 Avenue of States Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-203-8587",
      Website: "www.gandwtravel.com",
      Specialty: "Traveling, All Occasions"
    },
    "Grant Travel Agency": {
      Address: "1834 Edward Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-515-7062",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Traveling, All Occasions"
    }
  },
  fitness: {
    "Elijah's Supreme Gym": {
      Address: "420 Tilghman Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-898-5040",
      Website: "www.esupremegym.com",
      Specialty: "Fitness, All Body Types"
    },
    "Fitness Girl Gym": {
      Address: "2790 E. 15th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-762-8240",
      Website: "www.esupremegym.com",
      Specialty: "Fitness, All Body Types"
    }
  },
  retCloth: {
    "Enid and 4 Girls Boutique": {
      Address: "2200 Edgmont Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-203-8570",
      Website: "www.enidand4girls.com",
      Specialty: "Clothing, Accessories"
    },
    "Fatima & Iman's Closet": {
      Address: "824 Parker Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-800-1937",
      Website: "www.fatimaandiman.com",
      Specialty: "Clothing, Accessories"
    }
  },
  auto: {
    "Arthur's": {
      Address: "1019 Edgmont Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-626-1149",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "All Vehicle Issues"
    },
    "Johnson and Son Mechanics": {
      Address: "517 Pennell Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-504-8127",
      Website: "www.johnsonandsons.com",
      Specialty: "Auto Body Work"
    }
  },
  homeDec: {
    "Charisma Home Decor": {
      Address: "7790 Melrose Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-203-9045",
      Website: "www.charismahomedecor.com",
      Specialty: "Handcrafted Home Decor, Elegant Home Decor, All Styles"
    },
    "Lily's Home Decor": {
      Address: "1402 Ward Road Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-761-2990",
      Website: "www.lilydesign.com",
      Specialty: "All Styles"
    }
  },
  photo: {
    "Marple Photography": {
      Address: "618 Taylor Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "610-499-8615",
      Website: "www.marplephotography.com",
      Specialty: "All Styles, Occasions"
    },
    "Kyle's Photography": {
      Address: "216 W. 9th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-223-7831",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "Professional Shoots, All Styles, Occasions"
    }
  },
  musEnt: {
    "Mark's Studios": {
      Address: "2407 Linden Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-808-4256",
      Website: "www.markstudios.com",
      Specialty: "R&B, Hip Hop"
    },
    "CC Moore Recording Studio": {
      Address: "1420 Melrose Avenue Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-615-2009",
      Website: "www.ccmoorestudio.com",
      Specialty: "All Genres"
    }
  },
  paint: {
    "Ulysses's Paint": {
      Address: "2201 Edgmont Avenue Chester Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "267-298-0845",
      Website: "www.ulyssespaint.com",
      Specialty: "Mixing Paint, Selling All Paint Types"
    },
    "Dock Paint Supplies": {
      Address: "1007 W. 7th Street Chester, Pa 19013",
      PhoneNumber: "484-318-5190",
      Website: "N/A",
      Specialty: "All Paint Type Supplies"
    }
  }
}

// Add change event listener to the select
$("#businessListing_select").change(() => {
  getDataBaseEntries($("#businessListing_select option:selected").val(), businessListings);
});

function getDataBaseEntries(category, dataBase) {
  Object.keys(dataBase[category]).forEach(listing => {
    // Create A paragraph
    let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    // Set the text
    paragraph.innerText = listing;
    paragraph.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    // Add click event listener
    paragraph.addEventListener("click", function() { 
        // Clear the old html
        $("#infoTable").html("");
        // store the information in a variable
        let information = dataBase[category][listing];
        // `` == multiline string :) In a multiline string you can use "${}" to execute code
        $("#infoTable").html
        (`
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Phone Number</th>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>Specialty</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>${information.Address}</td>
                <td>${information.PhoneNumber}</td>
                <td>${information.Specialty}</td>
                <td>${information.Website}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        `);
      });
    // Append the paragraph
    $("#listingResults").append(paragraph);
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    table,th,td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<h4 class="title">Select a Category from the drop down menu to check your local businesses</h4>
<br>
<select id="businessListing_select" class="select-a-business">
    <option value="" selected="selected">- Select a business category -</option>
    <option value="hair">Hair</option>
    <option value="healBeauty">Health and Beauty</option>
    <option value="food">Food</option>
    <option value="travel">Travel</option>
    <option value="fitness">Fitness</option>
    <option value="retCloth">Retail and Clothing</option>
    <option value="auto">Automotive</option>
    <option value="homeDec">Home Decor</option>
    <option value="photo">Photography</option>
    <option value="musEnt">Music and Entertainment</option>
    <option value="paint">Paint</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p id="listingResults"></p>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div id="bottomOfPage">
    <div id="infoTable"></div>
</div>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Comment: The reason the arguments are blank when I call the function seeListingInfoTable is because I don't know how to get the values of what I need. I figured I would find that out after I get help with the table part. I want the title of the business user selected and business name as arguments. Just don't know how to get them.

Comment: Ohh but they you may add that to the question. You will get people confused.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. That you so much for your help.

Comment: Ill take a second look at it later

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated my code... now ... xD spent lost of time on that issue didn't I :P

Comment: Thank you. I think you're code is too advanced for my level. But thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Uhm just read it a bunch of times :) and write a comment if you need help :)

Comment: Just ask me about the parts you don't get :)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: 1st thing, I just transferred your code to my file and it's not running like it did in the snippet. Plus the button is gone.

Comment: yes :D because It automatically activates when you change the select :) And I don't know why it's not running

Comment: No but this probably has no `<script src="<path>"></script>` as you don't need to do that in the SO codeblock (I'm talking about the HTML file)

Comment: Ok thanks. How did you get the table to show once the once of the link options were clicked?

Comment: From my understanding this is how it goes. You create the element as p tag, then you made innerText set to "listing", then gave it a style decoration of underline, the event listener says if the element is clicked then put element #infoTable in .html, variable let information is set to dataBase[category][listing]; but I don't see how > dataBase[category][listing]; pulls the info out.

Comment: I have written it above: `` this chars lead to a multiline string and in a multiline string you can use ${<variable/code>} to insert code into it. Look at the `<td>` part of the string